# Refresh edit view from a partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

Is it possible to refresh an edit view from a method in my controller?

I have a partial view which does a callback to the controller. From this method i want to refresh my entire edit view based on the values i pass to this method.

```
  public ActionResult AssignPractice(Guid id, Guid doctorId)
    {
        var doctorViewModel = Map.This(_doctorService.GetDoctor(doctorId)).To<DoctorViewModel>();
        AddSelectLists(doctorViewModel);
        var practice = _practiceService.GetPractice(id);
        doctorViewModel.Practice = new PracticeSelectListViewModel()
            {Item = practice, DoctorId = doctorId, SelectList = _practices};
        return View("Edit", doctorViewModel);
    }
```

Thanks in advance,

Edit:

I will elaborate a little bit. The case i'm facing is as follows:

A doctor need to be assigned a practice and this doesn't only affect the doctors practiceId bu it also affects 20 other properties on my doctorviewmodel and they need to be reflected on the view. Perhaps i'm looking at this the wrong way by asking for the solution to the above.

Comment: What client side event is triggering this? Form submission? A click of a button outside the form? Markup, please...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478925/refreshing-parent-view-when-a-partial-views-form-is-submitted.

Comment: i am using a 3rd party control.
'  settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Doctor", Action = "AssignPractice", id = Model.Item.Id, doctorId = Model.DoctorId };

           settings.Properties.ClientSideEvents.SelectedIndexChanged = "function(s,e){cbbPractice.PerformCallback();}";'

Comment: The 3rd party control is inside an editorfor template

Comment: Perhaps the solution rashleigh proposes has is the direction i should go. Create a partial view for the practice specific data and refresh that view from my other partial view. But can you refresh one partial view from within another partial view?

Comment: And would the modelbinder be able to redirect the changes to the editforms model?

Comment: Personally I have used an Ajax call and on success reloaded the entire page but that is lazy loading by definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I used a bit of all the solutions to come to the solution that worked for my case.

Javascript:

```
function Doctor() {
this.id = null;
this.FirstName = "";
this.LastName = "";
this.Code = "";
this.PhoneNumber = "";
this.PhoneNumber2 = "";
this.PhoneNumberActive = 0;
this.PhoneNumber2Active = 0;
this.Email = "";
this.Practice = new Practice();

function AssignPractice() {

var myModel = new Doctor();
myModel.id = Id.value;
myModel.FirstName = FirstName.lastChangedValue;
myModel.LastName = LastName.lastChangedValue;
myModel.Code = Code.lastChangedValue;
myModel.PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber.lastChangedValue;
myModel.PhoneNumber2 = PhoneNumber2.lastChangedValue;
myModel.PhoneNumberActive = PhoneNumberActive.lastChangedValue;
myModel.PhoneNumber2Active = PhoneNumber2Active.lastChangedValue;
myModel.Email = Email.lastChangedValue;
myModel.Practice.id = cbbPractice.lastSuccessValue;
var postData = JSON.stringify(myModel);  
$.ajax({
    url: assignPracticeUrl,
    type: 'POST',
     data: postData,
    success: function (data) {
        $('#yourFormID').html(data);
    }
});
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Doctor", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "yourFormID" }))
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult AssignPractice(FormCollection form)
    {

        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var doctor = js.Deserialize<Doctor>(form[0]);
        var doctorViewModel = Map.This(_doctorService.GetDoctor(doctor.Id)).To<DoctorViewModel>();


        AddSelectLists(doctorViewModel);
        var practice = _practiceService.GetPractice(doctor.Practice.Id);
        var practiceViewModel = Map.This(practice).To<PracticeViewModel>();
        doctorViewModel.Practice = new PracticeSelectListViewModel() { Item = practice, SelectList = _practices };
        doctorViewModel.FirstName = doctor.FirstName;
        doctorViewModel.LastName = doctor.LastName;
        doctorViewModel.PhoneNumber = doctor.PhoneNumber;
        doctorViewModel.PhoneNumber2 = doctor.PhoneNumber2;
        doctorViewModel.PhoneNumberActive = doctor.PhoneNumberActive;
        doctorViewModel.PhoneNumber2Active = doctor.PhoneNumberActive;
        doctorViewModel.Email = doctor.Email;
        doctorViewModel.OpeningHours = practiceViewModel.OpeningHours;
        doctorViewModel.AppointmentHours = practiceViewModel.AppointmentHours;
        doctorViewModel.AddressViewModel = practiceViewModel.AddressViewModel;
        doctorViewModel.Website = practiceViewModel.Website;
        doctorViewModel.Labo = practiceViewModel.Labo;
        doctorViewModel.KeyChain = practiceViewModel.KeyChain;
        return PartialView("Edit",  doctorViewModel);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

How 'bout to call your controller method trhu JSON, using jQuery load function? You call your controller method, update your ViewModel and returns your Edit View or something else.

jQuery:

```
$('#buttonToRefresh').click(function () {
    $('#mainContent').load('@Url.Content("YourAction", "YourController")', $('#yourFormID').serialize());
});
```

View:

```
<div id="mainContent">
    @Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "yourFormID" })
    {
        // Your content goes here.
    }
</div>
```

Your controller remains the same.